# c# transaction scope with yield

Tags: c#, sql-server, yield, transactionscope

my requirement is to process multiple cost files, which has million of records. after processing and validation I have to add those records to database.

For better performance I am using "`yield`" in foreach loop and return one record at a time, process that record and immediately add that one record to database with file number. During this file reading process if I come across any data validation error, I throw InvalidRecordException.

My requirement is to delete all the records from table related that file. in short, even if one record is invalid I want to mark that file as invalid file and not add even a single record of that file to database.

can anyone help me here, how can i make use of TransactionScope here.

```
 public class CostFiles
        {
            public IEnumerable<string> FinancialRecords
            {
                get
                {
                    //logic to get list of DataRecords
                    foreach (var dataRecord in DataRecords)
                    {
                        //some processing... which can throw InvalidRecord exception 
                        yield return dataRecord;                       
                    }
                    yield break;
                }
            }
        }


        public void ProcessFileRecords(CostFiles costFile, int ImportFileNumber)
        {

            Database db = new Database();

            using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (var record in costFile.FinancialRecords)
                    {
                        db.Add(record, ImportFileNumber);

                    }
                }
                catch(InvalidRecordException ex)
                {
                    //here i want to delete all the records from the table where import file number is same as input paramter ImportFileNumber
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is `Database`? `TransactionScope` is (typically) used for distributed transaction support. Does `Database` provide support for this? Isn't there a native transaction concept you can use?

Comment: For this type of thing I would suggest using a stored procedure to handle your data work. Doing this row by agonizing row is going to be horribly slow with your millions of rows.

Comment: @DavidOsborne `TransactionScope` is not "typically used for distributed transaction support."  TransactionScope only elevates transactions to distributed transactions if you do not reuse the same SQL connection object.

Comment: SQL Server has bulk file import capability that would be much more efficient than what you're proposing here.

Comment: @CAbbott: It requires lots of processing and displaying polished data to user....so I went ahead with this approach...but ya I will surely think about SQL bulk file import option.

Comment: @SeanLange: yes db - database class has variuos methods which uses ADO.net and and make call to SPs.

Comment: @bansi  -SQL Server has Integration Services that can do imports and complex transformations much more efficiently. I would highly recommend taking a look: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx

Comment: @CAbbott: thanks for sharing link but isn't it Integration services is overly complex and hard to debug. .my solution allows me to incorporate changes quickly using c# and is pretty straight forward to debug issues - am i missing something?

Comment: @Bansi - My point was that,while implementing a programmatic approach my be easier for a developer, running thousands (maybe millions?) of db operations through ADO.net can place a huge burden on SQL Server vs. using something native. Obviously it's your choice.

Comment: @CAbbott: you are right. thanks for explaining...ya i am thinking about this option..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of a transaction scope is to create an "all or nothing" scenario, so either the whole transaction commits, or nothing at all commits.  It looks like you already have the right idea (at least in terms of the `TransactionScope`.  The scope won't actually commit the records to the database until you call `TransactionScope.Complete()`.  If `Complete()` is not called, then the records are discarded when you leave the transaction scope.  You could easily do something like this:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
{
    bool errorsEncountered = false;

    try
    {
        foreach (var record in costFile.FinancialRecords)
        {
            db.Add(record, ImportFileNumber);

        }
    }
    catch(InvalidRecordException ex)
    {
        //here i want to delete all the records from the table where import file number is same as input paramter ImportFileNumber
        errorsEncountered = true;
    }

    if (!errorsEncountered)
    {
        scope.Complete();
    }
}
```

Or you can just let the Add throw an exception and handle it outside of the transaction scope instead, as the exception will cause `Complete()` not to be called, and therefore no records added.  This method has the additional advantage of stopping processing of additional records when we already know it will do nothing.

```
try
{
    using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOptions.Required))
    {
        foreach(var record in costFile.FinancialRecords)
        {
            db.Add(record, ImportFileNumber);
        }

        // if an exception is thrown during db.Add(), then Complete is never called

        scope.Complete()
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // handle your exception here
    }
}
```

**EDIT** If you don't want your transaction elevated to a distributed transaction (which may have additional security/network requirements), make sure you reuse the same SqlConnection object for every database call within your transaction scope.

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("myConnectionString"))
{
    conn.Open();

    using (var scope = new TransactionScope(...))
    {
        foreach(var foo in foos)
        {
            db.Add(foo, conn);
        }

        scope.Complete();
    }
}
```

Comment: @ DVK : thanks for explanation. in case of exception if i call dispose method will it roll back (delete) all the records with same importFileNumber? OR in catch block I have to call stored procedure which will delete all the records from database with that importFileNumber?

Comment: If all of the records with that import file number were added as part of the same transaction, you don't need to call anything.  The records aren't actually committed to the database until `Complete()` is called, so just don't call complete.  Remember that deleting the records will also be considered part of the transaction if called within the scope, and therefore the records won't be deleted until `Complete()` is called.